# A question regarding "analytic" function in real analysis quiz

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, solution-verification

This particular question was asked to me by a junior as a part of his real analysis quiz and I was unable to solve it.

> Question: Let a function to be called "analytic" if for each $a\in\Bbb R$ there exists $\delta_a >0 $ such that on $(a-\delta_a, a+\delta_a)$ , $f$ has a power series expansion. Then show that zeroes of an "analytic" function on $\Bbb R$ have no limit points.

In complex analysis $f$ is said to be analytic at $a$ if $f$ is differentiable in each neighborhood of $a$ and alternatively it has a power series expansion which is convergent in some disc about $a$. So, it's analytic in complex analysis terms. So, I can use the well known result( proof) that zeroes of analytic functions are isolated in $\Bbb C$ hence also in $\Bbb R$ .

Is this approach right?

Comment: since power series have discs of convergence, any function as above can be extended to a complex analytic function on a small neighborhood of the reals

Comment: This is not true, in $\Bbb C$ or in $\Bbb R$, if $f$ is identically $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use it. Not because it works in $\Bbb C$ (many true statements about complex analytic functions are false in the case of real analytic functions), but because that proof works both for real and for complex analytic functions.